# ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 Logs out after a short time

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-code-401

Before I explain the issue I am facing I need to emphasise that this issue does not happen on my local computer. It only happens once I deploy the application to AWS (Windows Server + IIS).

The application has a number of Web API endpoints which have the [Authorize] attribute. The application uses Cookie Authentication.
You can see this website here:  https://saveonclouds.com

In Startup.cs I have persisted the cookie and have given it a custom name "saveoncloudscookie".

However about 10 minutes after signing in (both via username/password and Google) the user gets signed out and sees the Sign In page!

Since the issue happens in the hosting environment only it might be useful for me to explain the deployment:

Browser --> CloudFlare (SSL/TLS) --> Load Balancer (AWS) --> EC2 (only one instance)

In the above deployment model, the SSL certificate is terminated on the load balancer so the AWS EC2 receives the traffic with HTTP and not HTTPS.

I use the below code to try and persist the auth cookie but it does not seem to be working:

For Google Login:

services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(options =>
{
options.ClientId = AppSettings.Authentication.Google.ClientId;
options.ClientSecret = AppSettings.Authentication.Google.ClientSecret;
options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Accounts/AccessDenied";
options.CorrelationCookie.Expiration = new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0);
options.SaveTokens = true;

```
                options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                {
                    OnAccessDenied = loginFailureHandler =>
                    {
                        loginFailureHandler.Response.Redirect("/Accounts/Signin");
                        loginFailureHandler.HandleResponse();
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    OnTicketReceived = ticket =>
                    {
                        ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1);
                        ticket.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
                        ticket.Options.SaveTokens = true;
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };
            })
```

And

```html
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(option =>
            {
                option.Cookie.Name = "saveoncloudscookie";
                option.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                option.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                option.Cookie.MaxAge = new TimeSpan(1,0,0,0);
                option.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;

                option.LoginPath = "/Accounts/Signin";
                option.AccessDeniedPath = "/Accounts/AccessDenied";
                option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(authConfig.CookieExpirationHours);
                option.SlidingExpiration = true;

            });
```

I timed this and it seems in four minutes the user gets signed out!

Am I missing something?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue. I'm logged in to the app, visited couple of pages, but even after 5 min I don't get any 401 errors

Comment: I just tested it now and it happens. Just sign in to the website with Chrome and leave the website for about 10 minutes, then come back and click on the logo on the top left side of the screen. You will go to sign in page. The authentication cookie does not seem to be persisted although I explicitly do it in the code and I can see the cookie (called saveoncloudscookie) in Chrome with correct expiry date.

Comment: Not happening. I'm using Firefox 81, and logged in using my gmail account.

Comment: Can you check if you are getting correct value at `authConfig.CookieExpirationHours`. I mean just in case.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath  Yes it is set correctly. I suspect that the Auth Cookie is produced for HTTPS but then because traffic goes from AWS ALB to AWS EC2 over HTTP (and not HTTPS) the auth cookie is ignored. I reproduced this by running the website on my local machine in VS 2019, then sign in with HTTP, and going the Index/Home. The user is not authenticated so I see the sign in page again. How can I make the cookie valid for both https and http?

Comment: @abdusco  I just found that if I use a specific part of the site this happens. Will you mind sharing your email address with me so I invite you to my account on the website? Then you will have resources to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there was an EF Core exception happening which broke the worker process and so the application had to restart and re-authenticate. This was happening so silently and I only managed to find it by setting the logging level to Debug in Visual Studio and read every single line of text in Output window!